# Why am I getting an undeclared type 'PubNub' compiler error with Swift Cocoa App and bridging header?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods, pubnub

I am starting a new Cocoa Swift Project that is incorporating the PubNub SDK via CocoaPods with the following Podfile:

```
target 'myProject' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
pod 'PubNub', '~>4.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
end
target 'myProjectTests' do
end
```

In my auto-generated bridging header I have the import for PubNub as:

```
#import <PubNub/PubNub.h>
```

And my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain


class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var client:PubNub?

   func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    let config = PNConfiguration( publishKey: "Your_Pub_Key", subscribeKey:     "Your_Sub_Key")

    client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(config)

    client?.addListener(self)

    client?.subscribeToChannels(["Your_Channel"], withPresence: false)

    client?.publish("Swift + PubNub!", toChannel: "demo", compressed: false, withCompletion: nil)    }

func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult!) {
    println(message)
}

func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}


}
```

The project fails to build due to compiler errors on use of undeclared type PubNub.  I've checked the build settings and the Swift Compiler - Code Generation section shows it's pointed to the bridging header file of the target (auto-populated).

Using Xcode 6.4 and pods version 0.38.2

Comment: Please contact support@pubnub.com and we can offer you more direct help with this issue.

Comment: I prefer dealing directly with people when they post a question that does not contain enough information to answer. Plus this Podfile does not follow the syntax specified on [Cocoapods docs pages](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#link_with)

Comment: Ah, apparently if you include "use_frameworks!" then you'll be ok, though it's not clearly documented http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html

Answer (score 15):

### No Bridging-Header when Importing External Frameworks

**Straight from [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):**

> You can import external frameworks that have a **pure Objective-C** codebase, a **pure Swift** codebase, **or a mixed-language** codebase. [...] You can **import a framework** into any Swift file within a different target using the following syntax:

```
import FrameworkName
```

---

### Fix

Add `import PubNub` framework.

```swift
import UIKit
import PubNub

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var client:PubNub?
    // ...
}
```

With a single `import`, `PubNub` is declared, **auto-completes** in Xcode editor, compiles, links, builds and runs.

---

### Step-by-step Swift Framework Tutorial

*Since many comments below imply that Bridging-Headers are always required, wrongly so when using External Frameworks as is presently the case with the `use_frameworks!` directive in the `Podfile`, find here a **pure Swift** solution. It is followed by an `Xcode` project you can download and experience with.*

Unambiguously documented in the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_78), in concept *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C*, chapter *Mix and Match*, section **Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project**, paragraph *Importing External Frameworks*:

> The process for importing an external framework **is the same** whether the framework is written in a single language or contains files from **both languages**.

**Podfile**

```rb
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'SO-31642385' do
pod 'PubNub', '~>4.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.3'
end
```

**Install the pods**

```
] pod install

Downloading dependencies
Installing Alamofire (1.3.1)
Installing CocoaLumberjack (2.0.0)
Installing PubNub (4.0.4)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `SO-31642385.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
```

**Import Framework**

```swift
import UIKit
import PubNub

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var client:PubNub?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                         [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.client = PubNub()
        return true
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-31642385) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes/#SO-31642385).

Comment: That's unnecessary if you are using the bridging header correctly.

Comment: Please take a look at this project: https://github.com/jzucker2/StackOverflowSwiftBridgingHeader/tree/master

It does not `import PubNub` because it is included in the bridging header. Please feel free to consult Apple docs if you need more info on how this works, there's always more to learn.

Comment: "Any public Objective-C headers listed in this bridging header file will be visible to Swift. The Objective-C functionality will be available in any Swift file within that target automatically, without any import statements. Use your custom Objective-C code with the same Swift syntax you use with system classes." [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: @gurooj - please consider posting your comments as an answer so we can up vote or Jim Hankins can accept as answer.

Comment: It is the **other** way around. `Bridging Headers` are unnecessary if using `Frameworks` correctly. ` Pubnub` **is a Framework**. It is included with `use_frameworks!`. Just add `import PubNub` and bypass the bridge mechanism entirely.