# could not build module PubNub+Core.h in xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode8, pubnub

[image]I am using Xcode 8.0 and swift version 2.3 , but i am not able to build the code. I tried alot of options like header path change, Pod update, install simulator.But i am not able to build it. I have spent lot of time in this.

Some 
[image]

Attaching screenshot of bridging header file [image]

I have added screenshot of my podfile.lock. Looks like something is wrong with that. PubNub/Core. I don't why it coming as seperate. I have only Pod 'PubNub' in pod file.

Comment: What does your bridging header look like?

Comment: @BrianNickel : Please see the updated question with screenshot

Comment: The problem appears to be that PubNub isn't getting built before the project is building.  Are you opening the project `Foo.xcodeproj` or workspace `Foo.xcworkspace`?  If the workspace, does it work if you switch to the PubNub scheme first, build, switch back to your scheme, and build?

Comment: @BrianNickel: I tried to do this. Pubnub schema build fine. But when i switch back to project scheme, its giving me same error

Comment: @Nitya what deployment platform and version you need to build for?

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov   deployment target is 9.2. I have update PubNub pods to latest one. But still no help

Comment: Since you don't have any other dependencies on PubNub in your bridging header, you can try removing it from the bridging header and adding `import PubNub` in your Swift file. That was the solution to [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642385/why-am-i-getting-an-undeclared-type-pubnub-compiler-error-with-swift-cocoa-app?rq=1).

Comment: Agree with @BrianNickel what if you don't need to target iOS version lower than 8.0, you can use `use_frameworks!` directive in your _Podfile_, so frameworks will be integrated as dynamic binaries - this will allow to eliminate bridging header and use module imports (`import PubNub`)

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov: I am using use_frameworks! in podfile. Also, i added screenshot of podfile.lock which shows that PubNub/Core is also added. But i have only 'PubNub' in the podfile

Comment: @Nitya if you use `use_frameworks!` then there is no need in bridging header - just `import PubNub`. You can also try all this steps here: https://gist.github.com/parfeon/128f4fea81bcad7f0e8f1cb3eccda632

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov: The link you provided doesn't work.

Comment: @Nitya I've just tried and it works perfectly (even if logged out). Try using right-click copy it and open in new tab.

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov : Thank you so much for your help. The link you provided was awesome , i followed step by step and now , my code is building fine after 3 days. I want to accept this as answer so that others can also use that. I appriciate a lot your help and your knowledge

Comment: @Nitya I've added answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, provide solution in response. It has been suggested to follow steps from this list:

1. Install all iOS simulators after Xcode update
2. Open Xcode preferences (`Cmd + ,`) and navigate to "Locations" tab where will be shown path to "DerivedData" folder
3. Click on small circle with arrow on the right side of shown "DerivedData" path to open it in Finder
4. Quit Xcode
5. Remove "DerivedData" folder
6. Clean up CocoaPods (if integrated with it) caches by entering this in Terminal:

   `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods`
7. From project root (where Podfile is located) run this in Terminal:

   `pod deintegrate <project name>.xcodeproj`
8. Remove from project root (where `Podfile` is located) `Podfile.lock` file
9. From project root (where `Podfile` is located) run this in Terminal: `pod update`
10. Launch Xcode (hit `Shift + Cmd + K` just in case)
11. Try build project